# How to install Cinnamon with SLiM on Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, cinnamon

I have recently installed Arch Linux and since I'm new to hard it's a little hard to get around the things in here.

I wanted to know how I can instal cinnamon desktop environment with SliM display manager.

By now, I know how to install Arch system and boot into the root account. I have also installed the system X and currently I'm able see the basic GUI using:

```
 startx
```

I installed cinnamon and slim using:

```
 # pacman -S cinnamon
 # pacman -S slim
```

The problem, now, is that I don't know how to configure both the programs to start at boot.

**Edit**
Now, I tried installing the whole system again and configured everything properly (as far as I could understand).
Now, I am able to log into Cinnamon using my root account but then non root users are still not able to log into Cinnamon interface.

Additionally: I just wanted to ask how I can customize Cinnamon. If you could possibly point me at a guide, it would be great!

Comment: Try installing a login manager, `gdm3` or `lightdm` or `mdm`. That should simplify things.

Comment: I tried with lightdm but even it didn't work well. Can't seem to understand why. Whenevever the session manager starts a black screen pops up and then nothing appears.

Comment: right! It's really a duplicate because he asks the same question on superuser and unix.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice the rules of duplication. I'll make sure that I don't make such a mistake again.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the official wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Slim
Then ask for specific problem if you have.